# in a js modal window how do you set a background color property

Tags: javascript, colors

I've tried using:

backgroundcolor:#00000,

and

background-color:#00000,

color:#e5fbff,

Here's what i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var IsSubscribed;

<?php

$IsSubscribed='false';

if (Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn())
{

    if (Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()) -> isSubscribed())
    {
        $IsSubscribed='true';
    }


}



?>
 IsSubscribed=<?php echo($IsSubscribed); ?>;

 if (!IsSubscribed&&document.body.offsetWidth!=320)
 {







    var expireAt = Mage.Cookies.expires;

        expireAt = new Date();
        expireAt.setTime(expireAt.getTime() + 3600000);




if (!Mage.Cookies.get('auto_pop_newsletter'))
{


    Dialog.info($('newsletter_sign_up').innerHTML, 
     { 
     draggable:true,             
     resizable:false,             
     closable:true,             
     className:'magento',             
     windowClassName:'video-window',             
     title:'Video Window',             
     top:100,             
     width:680,             
     height:400,             
     zIndex:20000,
     "background-color":"#e5fbff",             
     recenterAuto:true,             
     hideEffect:Element.hide,             
     showEffect:Element.show,             
     id:'video_window',             
     onClose: function () {             }         
     }); 

     $$('#modal_dialog_message form')[0].id='pop_newsletter';

     $$('#modal_dialog_message form .pop_newsletter_source')[0].value=1;

     pop_newsletter = new VarienForm('pop_newsletter', true);


    Mage.Cookies.set('auto_pop_newsletter', 1,expireAt);

}



 }


 function web_pop_newsletter(){

    Dialog.info($('newsletter_sign_up').innerHTML, 
     { 
     draggable:true,             
     resizable:false,             
     closable:true,             
     className:'magento',             
     windowClassName:'video-window',             
     title:'Video Window',             
     top:100,             
     width:320,             
     height:400,             
     zIndex:20000,             
     recenterAuto:true,             
     hideEffect:Element.hide,             
     showEffect:Element.show,             
     id:'video_window',             
     onClose: function () {             }         
     }); 

     $$('#modal_dialog_message form')[0].id='pop_newsletter';

     $$('#modal_dialog_message form .pop_newsletter_source')[0].value=3;

     pop_newsletter = new VarienForm('pop_newsletter', true);


 }

//]]>
</script>
```

I've done some searching but can't seem to figure out the correct syntax. Nothing seems to work..

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**update**: I tried both steps below.

Comment: Well, you have too few zeroes and not enough quotation marks. Also, this isn’t a “JS modal window”. It comes from some plugin. Please provide context.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that.. i need a specific color so i just but 0's down.. updated above.  color:#e5fbff